# How to set pagingOptions of ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have used ngGrid in my page. First time or page loading time I have render ng-grid without set pagination option. After that I want to set paging option by clicking a button. How is it possible?

```
$scope.persons = [{ name: "Moroni", age: 50 },
          { name: "Tiancum", age: 43 },
          { name: "Jacob2", age: 27 },
          { name: "Jacob3", age: 27 }];
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'persons',
    plugins: [new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()]
};
```

I have set ng-grid in html page.

Now I want to show ng-grid pager after clicking on show pager button. What should I do?

```
$scope.ShowPager= function () {
     $scope.pagingOptions = {
         pageSizes: [10, 20, 30, 500, 1000, 5000], //page Sizes
         pageSize: 10, //Size of Paging data
         currentPage: 1 //what page they are currently on
     };
     $scope.gridOptions.pagingOptions = $scope.pagingOptions;

     $scope.gridOptions.showFooter = true;

     $scope.gridOptions.enablePaging = true;

     $scope.gridOptions.totalServerItems = 'totalServerItems';
}
```

Comment: @AliAmiri: Don't make rubbish edits like that.

Comment: @staticx I'm just fix codestyle!

Comment: @AliAmiri: It really should be more substantial.

Comment: @staticx you are right :)

Answer (score 0):

this is how i have set it...

```
            gridOptions.pageOptions = {
                pageSizes: [20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000],
                pageSize: 20,
                currentPage: 1,
                totalServerItems: 0
            };

            gridOptions.pagingOptions = gridOptions.pageOptions;
```

why did i do it like this.. i dont know, but its working....

may be early days of angular & copy paste effect :)

**EDIT**

to enable paging on button click do

```
$scope.gridOptions.enablePaging = false; //disable by default

$scope.enablePaging = function(){
       $scope.gridOptions.enablePaging = true;
}

<button ng-click="enablePaging()"></button>
```

Comment: Please see my whole question. I want to activate grid pagination by clicking on a button.

Comment: Thanks, no. It is my observation.